# Condensing Interval Time in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a large data set containing half hour intervals in one column and numerical values in the adjacent column.  Here is an example of the data in a pivot table.

[image: example]

I would like to be able to sum the data into hourly intervals in the pivot table (e.g. 12am, 1am, 2am, etc). Is there a way to accomplish this in the pivot table or would I have to manipulate the data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @pnuts said, but here's a full-blown example.

[image: Original Data]

[image: Pivot]

[image: Group 1]

[image: Group 2]

[image: Result]

Comment: Well done indeed! Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a column with

```
=LEFT(Cell,2) & Right(Cell,2)
```

Where cell contains your timestamp, throw that column on top of your time column in the pivot.

You can also probably use DAX time intelligence, but this seems like a cut and dry solution.